# How to add canonical tag for product pages as domainname.com/category/subcategory/product.html

Tags: magento-1.9, product, canonical

Canonical tag for product pages of ([eleczo](http://www.eleczo.com/)).

I need solution how to add a canonical tag for product pages as domainname.com/category/subcategory/product.html in MAGENTO 1.9.1.1.

Because, the same product page is getting listed with two diff URLs as 
"1. domainname.com/product.html", 
"2. domainname.com/category/subcategory/product.html"

Now, I am worried about copied content though there nothing copied or duplicate content.

Yes, I can avoid it by enabling canonical tag for product at the backend. But, this will as canonical as domainname.com/product.html. But, I want full path including category and subcategory. So, how can I achieve it?

Comment: `System > Configuration > Catalog -> Search Engin Optimization -> Select Yes in "Use canonical link meta tag"`

Answer (score 0):

To enable canonical meta tag on the product page:

Magento has canonical meta tags build in out of the box. In order to enable them go to:

```
Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization
```

Refer to the attached screen shot

http://www.amanweb.in/magento-enable-canonical-meta-tag.jpg

Comment: Thank you. But even I know these options but enabling it for product pages adding a canonical tag as domainname.com/product.html instead of domainname.com/category/subcategory/product.html....I want 2nd URL to be as my canonical tag for product pages....any solution for this?

Comment: You want product url with category but the problem is if product is assign to multiple category which url should you use.

Comment: In my case there is nothing like that, I am not assigning a single product in multiple categories. So, now whats the solution? Also, in future if I add single product in multiple category then I would prefer the main category URL, even how to handle this..can u please suggest me?

Comment: use this extension that will help you to use product url with category in product page - https://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/seo-canonical-url-extension.html

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your Magento 2 admin panel.

click stores->settings-> configuration

Go to catalog in the left panel.

Click search engine optimizations

Set both Use Canonical Link Meta Tag for Categories and Use Canonical Link Meta Tag for Products to yes.

Here we follow the steps, your work will be done because this is the best process

And you can visit our website to see the normal canonical tag. https://www.iamdeepa.co.in/